# Question regarding designing workflows

Tags: list, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, custom-list

I'm a complete newbie to the SP design world and am trying to create a form with the following parts. I've tried reading various guides, but they're either super generic or more technical than I'm capable of understanding right now. This is a side project and I've been stuck for a couple of weeks now, so any help is appreciated.

- Once submitted, it triggerss an email alert to a particular group for
  review, CC's the creator, and CCs the creators supervisor (all
  information requested/provided in the form and populated by the
  creator using People Picker, so no need to do any SP lookups there)
- Any comments or additional information needed by those reviewers
  should trigger an email back to the creator
- Once approved, the form then needs to be sent to another group as an alert that it was approved
- Only the approvers should be able to see the entire list/library of requests -- requestors should only be able to see their own entries

I've got the form designed and the initial email alert functioning, but I'm having trouble with the back and forth portion. My process in SP Designer looks a bit like this:

Step 1:

```
If created by Person A // Current Item:Created By
or modified by Person B (reviewer)  // hard-coded email address
or modified by Person C (reviewer)  // hard-coded email address
or modified by Person A (creator) // Current Item:Created By
  Email person@domain.com   // CC section of this email uses the SP lookup to pull the Creator's email and the email from the supervisor People Picker field
```

Step 2:

```
If modified by Person B
or modified by Person C
or modified by Person A
  If *Approval Status* equals *0;#Approved*
  Email person@domain.com  // CC section of this email uses the SP lookup to pull the Creator's email and the email from the supervisor People Picker field, plus the approval group
  then Email accounting@company.com
```

Step 3 and 4 would be pending (i.e. more input from creator needed) and denied.

Could someone point me in the right direction for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will address the sending of notifications 1st then the creation of those notifications. You can add as many conditions as you like.

Okay user your approved field and the created user 1st

- If Modifed by = Created by and Approved not = to true (whatever you are using)

  - Send email to b and c
- Else if modified by = B and Approved not = to true

  - Send email to c and Creator
- else if modified by = C and approved not = to true

  - Send email to Creator and B

Now as to get data in the emails you only want the New information I am assuming. I would have two multi line text fields. I would use one of the fields to display text and one to be an entry field. Let me explain.

The Display text field would only show on the view and not new or edit forms. The entry field would only show on the Edit and New forms.

You will use the Entry field to put new information into your emails. You will have workflow update the display field.

Set field "display field to =

[display field]
[Modifed by] - [modifed]
[entery field]

Set field "entery field to = "enter new note here"

Please let me know if I am off or missing some part of the workflow you need.